# Chrome Extension : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I was creating a chrome extension and wanted to make an overlay window but am getting this error : (

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

This is the `.js` file that I am getting an error in

```
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
        onclick, false)


    function onclick (){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {createDiv: {width: "100px", height: "100px", innerHTML: "Hello"}}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.confirmation);
        });
    });
    }
}, false)
```

My `.html` file is just a simple html file with a button

Comment: Move your `<script ...` tag to the end of file before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is running your javascript file before the HTML page fully loaded, so the button doesn't exist yet.

Workaround to that could be to put your script at the bottom of your page, or use the Load of DomContentLoad event like so:

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
        onclick, false)
}
```